# Oracle Regex at least "1" match in a serie

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question related with oracle sql regex function.

I have a series of zeros and ones. It can vary as:

Ex:

```
1111000
000001
0101111
10000
```

If there is at least one "1" in this serie, then I want to output as "1"
otherwise I want to ouput "0". So I tried something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1,1,1,0','[0,]||[1]+','') FROM DUAL
```

However this just outputs "1's" out of series excluding "0"

So my question: How can I achieve this on oracle sql?

Comment: In you example, should the string '1,1,1,0' be considerd as a single "sequence", thus returning '1' or as a list of sequences, this returning, '1,1,1,0'?

Comment: The string '1,1,1,0' be considered as a single "sequence" and it should return me 1 since it satiesfies "at least one '1'" rule @Aleksej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well and you only need to check whether a string contains '1' or not, you may not need regexp and [`INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/INSTR.htm#SQLRF00651) could be enough:

```
select case
        when instr(yourString, '1') = 0
           then '1 is not in the string'
           else '1 is in the string'
        end
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE %1%' will work for you as well...

```
with dt as (
select '00000000' seq from dual union all
select '00011000' seq from dual)
select 
  seq,
  case when seq like '%1%' then 1 else 0 end as res
from dt;

SEQ             RES
-------- ----------
00000000          0 
00011000          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Later on I also figured out that this also worked for me:

```
 SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE( 'MY_STRING' , '.?+1?[0,]', '') as COLUMN_NAME
  FROM dual;
```